# Can't subscribe to WebFlux stream in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rxjs, spring-webflux, reactive

I wrote a server that produces stream thanks to Flux from WebFlux (Spring boot). The method that provid stream

```
public Flux<Data> getStream() {

        Flux<Data> initialData = Flux.just(this.data);

        Flux<Data> periodicData = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                .map(tick -> this.data);

        return Flux.concat(initialData, periodicData);
}
```

I have also defined a request handler :

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> streamData(ServerRequest request) {
        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .body(DataService.getStream(), Data.class);
}
```

And a request router:

```
RouterFunction<?> routes (RequestHandler requestHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions
                .route(RequestPredicates
                        .GET("/data"),
                        requestHandler::streamData);
}
```

When I'm using postman I could easly subscribe to this stream
[image]

But when I'm trying to subscribe to this stream with my angular client I got this
[image]

Here, my Webflux client in angular

```
getStream() {
    return this.http.get<Data>(this.apiUrl+'/data', {observe : 'events'}).subscribe(
      (event : HttpEvent<Data>) => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response){
          console.log('Message : ', event.body);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: I have find a way to process. Indeed, by using EventSource I can easly subscribe to the data stream. For further explanations look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events